# hide textbox if jquery list has the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i hide the textbox when the class active is found in UL > LI

when  i should show its label and textbox otherwise, it should be hidden. i am trying to get the value of selected checkbox and hide it but unable to reach there.

```
$('ul.multiselect-container').has('li.active').css('display', 'none');

<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1"> Paypal</label></a>

    </li>
    <li class="active"><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2"> Stripe</label></a>

    </li>
    <li class=""><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3">Beanstream</label></a>

    </li>
</ul>
<label for="Configuration_paypalId" class="control-label">Paypal Id</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_paypalId" name="Configuration[paypalId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
<br>
<label for="Configuration_stripeId" class="control-label">Stripe Id</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_stripeId" name="Configuration[stripeId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
<br>
<label for="Configuration_beanId" class="control-label">Bean Id</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_beanId" name="Configuration[beanId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
```

**Update**

Sorry if question is not clear,
when i click the first checkbox, say paypal then only paypal label and text box should appear below, the remaining text box 2 and its labels should hide. we need to loop through UL tag with each() i guess.

Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nzw7LoL0/5/

**update 2**

i am unable to add a class to the div called option and option 1 since html is generated with a framework. so i need to hide the row which has the class `.control-group` http://jsfiddle.net/d280wqr4/5/

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function () { // Apply change listener to checkboxes
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // If this checkbox is checked, show the relevant element
        $('.option' + $(this).prop('value'))find('.control-group').show();
    } else { // Otherwise, hide the relevant element
        $('.option' + $(this).prop('value')).find('.control-group')hide();
    }
});


<div class="control-group "><label for="Configuration_paypalId" class="control-label">Paypal Id</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_paypalId" name="Configuration[paypalId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 option option1"><p class="help-block">Merchant id or email of the Paypal account</p></div></div>

    <div class="control-group "><label for="Configuration_stripeId" class="control-label">Stripe Id</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" id="Configuration_stripeId" name="Configuration[stripeId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 option option2"><p class="help-block">Stripe id or email of the Stripe account</p></div></div>
```

Comment: all those input fields?

Comment: @ArunPJohny when i click first checkbox, say paypal then only paypal label and text box should appear, the remaining text box 2 and its labels should hide. we need to loop through UL tag with each() i guess

Comment: your question needs me clarification its hard for us to understand what you actually want?

Comment: @JoshStevens please look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nzw7LoL0/8/ when i click on paypal in the checkbox Paypal Id label and its text box should exist. the remaining 2 textbox and label should hide. am i clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a common class so that the selector becomes simple

```
<input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_beanId" name="Configuration[beanId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 classname">
```

then

```
$('input.classname').toggle($('.multiselect-container li.active').length == 0);//hides input with class `classname` if `li` has `active` class
$('ul.multiselect-container').has('li.active').hide();//hides the ul if li has active class
```

---

```js
$('.multiselect-container input:checkbox').click(function(){
  var type = $(this).data('type');
  $('.'+type).toggle(this.checked);
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active')
});

$('.payid').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1" data-type="paypal"> Paypal</label></a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2" data-type="stripe"> Stripe</label></a></li>
  <li class=""><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3" data-type="bean">Beanstream</label></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="paypal payid">
  <label for="Configuration_paypalId" class="control-label">Paypal Id</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_paypalId" name="Configuration[paypalId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
</div>
<div class="stripe payid">
  <label for="Configuration_stripeId" class="control-label">Stripe Id</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_stripeId" name="Configuration[stripeId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
</div>
<div class="bean payid">
  <label for="Configuration_beanId" class="control-label">Bean Id</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_beanId" name="Configuration[beanId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
</div>
```

Comment: when i click on first checkbox, say paypal. then only paypal label and text box should appear, the remaining text box 2 (stripe and bean) and its labels should hide. we need to loop through UL tag with each() i guess

Comment: @dev1234 try the update - there is html changes also

Comment: @dev1234 you can have  a single handler which will add the class and set the visibility

Comment: oh ok. can you provide a js fiddle for that please?

Comment: @ArunPJohny This needs to be a change listener rather than a click listener. Disabled checkboxes can still be clicked. Also data attributes aren't necessary.

Comment: @ArunPJohny it has a issue, its not showing the textboxes did u see? hides only the label. text box's are gone forever. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d280wqr4/7/

Comment: @ArunPJohny it seems like its working fine in jsfiddle, but when i copy it to my code, the first control-group gets a style automatically as display:block. so the rest  of the rows hides expect the first one. when i remove your JS code, the automatically added display:block disappears. any idea?

Comment: whether the first checkbox is checked by default

Comment: @dev1234 add an alert like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d280wqr4/11/) and see

Comment: @dev1234 somehow you are marking the first checkbox as checked.... may be try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d280wqr4/12/

Comment: @ArunPJohny no i am not. this is how it appears when i have not selected any. <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1"> Paypal</label></a></li> <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2"> Stripe</label></a></li>

Comment: @ArunPJohny and its hidden. the whole code is, <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1"> Paypal</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2"> Stripe</label></a></li></ul>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83422/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-dev1234).

Comment: why do u have a var $input (dollar which is a php part here?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a "change" listener to the checkboxes, and then work out if they are checked and show/hide another element based upon this information. You do need a class or id that matches the value property of the checkbox.

The below example should be working as you're hoping.

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() { // Apply change listener to checkboxes
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // If this checkbox is checked, show the relevant element
    $('.option' + $(this).prop('value')).show();
  } else { // Otherwise, hide the relevant element
    $('.option' + $(this).prop('value')).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.option {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />Paypal
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" />Stripe
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" />Beanstream
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="option option1"> <!-- The number refers to the value of the checkbox -->
  <label for="Configuration_paypalId" class="control-label">Paypal Id</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_paypalId" name="Configuration[paypalId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
</div>
<div class="option option2">
  <label for="Configuration_stripeId" class="control-label">Stripe Id</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_stripeId" name="Configuration[stripeId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
</div>
<div class="option option3">
  <label for="Configuration_beanId" class="control-label">Bean Id</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_beanId" name="Configuration[beanId]" maxlength="60" class="span4">
</div>
```

#### Update based upon more information

If you can't edit the html because it's dynamically generated, you'll need to do it based upon the index. This will only work if the order of the checkboxes matches the other of the inputs, but if it's dynamically generated then I don't see why this shouldn't be the case.

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() { // Apply change listener to checkboxes
  var index = parseInt($(this).prop('value')) - 1; // Make the index zero based
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // If this checkbox is checked, show the relevant element
    $('.control-group:eq(' + index + ')').show();
  } else { // Otherwise, hide the relevant element
    $('.control-group:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.control-group {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />Paypal
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" />Stripe
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" />Beanstream
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>------------------------------</p>
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="Configuration_paypalId" class="control-label">Paypal Id</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_paypalId" name="Configuration[paypalId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 option option1" />
  <p class="help-block">Merchant id or email of the Paypal account</p>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="Configuration_stripeId" class="control-label">Stripe Id</label>
  <input type="text" id="Configuration_stripeId" name="Configuration[stripeId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 option option2" />
  <p class="help-block">Stripe id or email of the Stripe account</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible for you to change the code to hide the row when class is control-group . check this http://jsfiddle.net/d280wqr4/4/

Comment: since the HTML's are generated its difficult to add a class called option and option 1. so i have added it to text field but i want to hide the div tag also. please check my last fiddle.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to use the index: http://jsfiddle.net/d280wqr4/6/. This will work as long as the order of the checkboxes matches the order of the inputs.

Comment: everything is fine, but i am unable to put this style .control-group {
    display: none;
} because there are other rows in the form which also has the same class for div.  how to hide the rows div.control-group which has paypalId and stripeId.

Comment: @dev1234 Are they in their own parent container?

Comment: then do `.scheduler-border .control-group { display: none; }` to only target the control groups within that fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change your markup little bit then you can make use of `data-*` attribute this way:

```js
    $('.dropdown-menu :checkbox').change(function(e) {
      var target = $(this).data('target');
      $('.' + target).toggle();
    });
```

```css
.paypal, .stripe, .beanstream{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li class="">
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" data-target='paypal' value="1">Paypal</label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" data-target='stripe' value="2">Stripe</label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" data-target='beanstream' value="3">Beanstream</label>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<label for="Configuration_paypalId" class="control-label paypal">Paypal Id</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_paypalId" name="Configuration[paypalId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 paypal">
<br>
<label for="Configuration_stripeId" class="control-label stripe">Stripe Id</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_stripeId" name="Configuration[stripeId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 stripe">
<br>
<label for="Configuration_beanId" class="control-label beanstream">Bean Id</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="Configuration_beanId" name="Configuration[beanId]" maxlength="60" class="span4 beanstream">
```

Comment: Better to check for the checkbox being checked or not and do an action based upon that, otherwise you leave open the possibility of them becoming out of sync and a "checked" checkbox hides it instead of showing it.

Comment: @JamieBarker is it? but as OP has updated the question so it seems that `radios` are better choice instead.

Comment: Yes, you're toggling the visibility based upon every change event. If one of the checkboxes starts the page as checked from some reason, perhaps a browser back button caching or something, then it's not going to be working properly.

Comment: Your answer works, it just has _potential_ flaws you might not have considered :)